# Update multiple checbox Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I have a table association

```
ID_USER_CAR | USER_ID | CAR_ID | DELETED_AT

1               2         3        
2               2         5
3               2         10
```

The problem is on update... because the next time when i'm editing ...the user 2 will want only the car 3 and another car from list...for example car 7.

```
 @foreach($cars as $car)
     <label style="display:block" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input @if(in_array($car->car_id, $userCars)) checked @endif type="checkbox" name="cars[]" value="{{ $car->id_car }}" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-indicator"></span><span class="custom-control-description">{{ $car->name }}</span>
     </label>
  @endforeach
```

so after the update..the table will look something like this

```
 ID_USER_CAR | USER_ID | CAR_ID | DELETED_AT

    1               2         3        
    2               2         5    2017-10-15
    3               2         10   2017-10-15
    4               2         7
```

Comment: Clan you explain better what is happening?

Comment: I don't know how to make the update part..because on edit I can change the checkboxes..and I don't know what to delete..what to update..and insert.. if the checkboxes values are other @Troyer

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with Eloquent [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) in laravel:

assuming that your table's name is `car_user`:

create 2 models: Car and User:
in Car model add users() relation:

```
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany( User::class, 'car_user', 'car_id', 'user_id' );
    }
```

in User model:

```
    public function cars(){
        return $this->belongsToMany( Car::class, 'car_user', 'user_id', 'car_id' );
    }
```

now you can do this in blade:

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
     <label style="display:block" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input {{ $car->users->find($user->user_id) ? 'checked' : '' }} type="checkbox" name="cars[]" value="{{ $car->id_car }}" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-indicator"></span><span class="custom-control-description">{{ $car->name }}</span>
     </label>
  @endforeach
```

now for updating:
in many to many relations updates you have to detach all rows first, and then attach the new ones (checked ones):
in `controller`:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user->cars()->detach();
    foreach ($request->cars as $car)
        $user->cars()->attach($car);
}
```